# Fetch data from a smart contract array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, solidity

I have a factory smart contract that deploys another smart contract.

In the factory contract I have this function

```
address[] public migrations;

...

function getMigrations() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return migrations;
    }
```

after the migration is pushed in this array, I want to display a list of addresses on the first page but I really can't.

This is what I've tried:

```
import React from "react";
import web3 from "./web3";
import factory from "./factory";
import AccordionExampleStyled from "./components/Acordeon";
import { Card, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'



class App extends React.Component {

  static async getInitialProps() {
    const migration = await factory.methods.getMigrations().call();

    return { migration };
  
  };

renderCampaigns() {
    const items = this.props.migration.map((address) => {
      return {
        header: address,
        description: (
          <Button>See migration</Button>
        ),
        fluid: true,
      };
    });
    return <Card.Group items={items} />;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      
      <div>
      <center>
        <h2>MigrationHelper by DRIVENecosystem</h2>
        <p>
         <p><AccordionExampleStyled /></p>
          <p>List of all migrations </p>
          <p></p>
          {this.renderCampaigns()}
        </p>
       </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
  };
  

export default App;
```

I got this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

P.S. I am a newbie in React.js and web3

Edit: I also tried that option, but nothing

```
import React from "react";
import web3 from "./web3";
import factory from "./factory";
import AccordionExampleStyled from "./components/Acordeon";


import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'



class App extends React.Component {

  static async getInitialProps() {
   const migrations = await factory.methods.getMigrations().call();

    return { migrations };
  }
 
   renderMigrations(){
   const items = this.props.migrations.map((migrations) => {return{migrations}});
    return <li>{items}</li>;
} 

  render() {
    return (
      
      <div>
      <center>
        <h2>MigrationHelper by DRIVENecosystem</h2>
        <p>
         <p><AccordionExampleStyled /></p>
          <p>List of all migrations </p>
          <p>{this.props.renderMigrations}</p>

        </p>
       </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
  };
  

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

##### The problem

`migrations` is not present on the first render. so mapping through it, cause the error.

##### The Solution

Just need to check the `migrations` data has arrived and has content before mapping it:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  static async getInitialProps() {
   const migrations = await factory.methods.getMigrations().call();

    return { migrations };
  }
 
   const renderMigrations = () => {
     return this.props.migrations.map((migration) => {
        return(
           <div>
             <li>{migration.name}</li>)
             <p>{migration.detail}</li>)
           </div>
        )
      })
   } 

  render() {
    const items = this.props.migration;
   
    return (
      
      <div>
      <center>
        <h2>MigrationHelper by DRIVENecosystem</h2>
        <p>
         <p><AccordionExampleStyled /></p>
          <p>List of all migrations </p>
          <p>
             {
               items?.length > 0 && renderMigrations
             }
          </p>
        </p>
       </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
 
export default App;
```

In the `renderMigrations` method, I used e sample to show the `migration` detail with `li` and `p` elements, since the `migrations` array does not exist in your question, I just take an example. You should change it with your requirement in the application.

Comment: Thank you @novonimo. Can you tell me if this should be the final version? https://codeshare.io/AdvobN
Using this version I still can't see the "migrations": https://imgur.com/a/H6RrHDm

I am sure that the integration with the smart contract is not wrong, because when I use this code [https://codeshare.io/gL0dlV] I can see element 1 of the string: https://imgur.com/a/OfViBIQ

Comment: I've update my answer right now, please take a look @Paul-ConstantinSocarde